# Icons from .qrc wouldn't show outside Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qresource

I have a qrc resource file containing a few icons initialized by Q_INIT_RESOURCE(icons) and added in ui file (designer).

When I run it in Qt Creator everything shows as it should, but there are no icons showing while running the .exe outside the IDE. There must by some problem in directory path to the icons but I cannot find it. I tried putting the .exe, .qrc file and folder with the icons to the same directory but without luck.

Comment: How your qrc file looks like?

Comment: The .qrc file does not contain the actual icons, only a list of files used, so there is no point in placing it next to the .exe file. What needs to happen is that the .qrc file is compiled (with an intermediate step). If you are using a .pro file, make sure to add it using a RESOURCES entry (e.q. RESOURCES += myicon.qrc)

Comment: in the .pro file I have  RESOURCES += \ icons.qrc and in qrc prefix "/" and than folder "icons" containing actual pictures

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED ... I didn't have Qt5Svgd.dll in the directory with .exe
Thanks anyway ;)